# LaTex ChemFig how to put parentheses around polymer?

Tags: chemfig

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

{
\chemname
{\chemfig{HO-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]OH}}
{Diol}\\
\bigskip
\bigskip
$+$\\
\chemname
{\chemfig{([3]N=C=O)-[0]*6(=-=([0]-*6(=-=(-[0]([9]N=C=O))-=-))-=-)}}
{Isocyanates}\\
\bigskip
\bigskip
$\downarrow$\\
\bigskip
\bigskip
\chemname
{\chemfig{-O(=[2]C)-N(-[6]H)-(*6(=-=(-*6(=-=(-N(-[6]H)-O(=[2]C)-O-O-)-=-))-            
=-))}}
{Polyurethane}
}

\end{center}



\end{document}
```

How can I put parentheses around the "Polyurethane" structure so that the parentheses intersect the two outer bond?

Much thanks!

Comment: Tags [tag:latex3] and [tag:pdftex] are _not_ for general LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

With `\polymerdelim` (introduced in version 1.33 of `chemfig`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\chemname
{\chemfig{-[@{upleft,0.5},1]O(=[2]C)-N(-[6]H)-(*6(=-=(-*6(=-=(-N(-[6]H)-O(=[2]C)-O-O-[@{upright,0.5},1])-=-))-            
=-))}}
{Polyurethane}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 45pt, depth = 40pt, indice = n]{upleft}{upright}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]